# Apache Config with Wildcard/Non-Wildcard Subdomain Mix

Tags: apache, wildcard

I have the domain, we'll call it "mydomain.com" and I want the following virtual hosts set up to resolve in the following way:

- mydomain.com / www.mydomain.com to point to /var/www/
- dev.mydomain.com to point to /var/www/dev/
- *.mydomain.com (all *other* subdomains) to point to /var/www/old

My apache configuration is currently set up as:

```
NameVirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80

<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
 ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/old
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
 ServerName mydomain.com
 ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
 ServerAlias dev.mydomain.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Unfortunately, this is not working as I expected. With this configuration, only the first (wildcard) VirtualHost entry works properly.

What is the right way to configure Apache to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place the wildcard entry last in the file. Apache will use the first VirtualHost that matches the Host header being sent by the browser.

Comment: Is it possible to write separate configuration files for each of the above Virtual Hosts or is it necessary to be in the same file to allow precedence order?

Comment: @activatedGeek If they're in separate files, precedence is based on filename. In a new Ubuntu distribution you'll find the default file named `000-default` for that reason. Doesn't hurt to put them in the same file so precedence is guaranteed.

Comment: @ceejayoz: How can I set wild card in document root. One of my folder specified in Document root  gets changed during automated deployment.